# How to assign self-signed certificate to all users connected to a intranet domain?

Tags: ssl, iis, intranet, self-signed-certificate

I am trying to publish asp.net application to iis server with https protocol in intranet domain (local), which requires ssl certificate. I created self-signed certificate using Jexus Manager. But i am facing problem to run my web application on other computers which are connected to my intranet domain.
It is giving error "Your Connection is not private".
How to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you know the Group Policy System of a Windows domain? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/distribute-certificates-to-client-computers-by-using-group-policy

Comment: 1) Set up Active Directory 2) Set up Active Directory Certificate Services. 3) Get a valid certificate from AD for your web server. Never use a self-signed certificate beyond local development.

Comment: As far as I know, the self-signed certificate is a certificate that is not signed by a certificate authority (CA). Since this is not signed by a certificate authority (CA), your client will regard it as the un-secure connection. The right way is you should setup Active Directory Certificate Services in the domain server and generate and request certificates through IIS. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/using-the-microsoft-certificate-authority-to-get-rid-of-those-self-signed-certs).

Comment: @BrandoZhang Thanks for sharing this article it helped me a lot.

Comment: If you feel my comment is helpful, I will generate a reply, please mark it as answer, it will help other people who faces the same issue find the answer more easily. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the self-signed certificate is a certificate that is not signed by a certificate authority (CA). Since this is not signed by a certificate authority (CA), your client will regard it as the un-secure connection. The right way is you should setup Active Directory Certificate Services in the domain server and generate and request certificates through IIS. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/using-the-microsoft-certificate-authority-to-get-rid-of-those-self-signed-certs).